# jQuery animate API not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
function xava(target_url, elementID) {
    jQuery(elementID).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=135"
    }, 1500);
    window.location.href = target_url;
}
jQuery('[id^="nav-arrow"]').click(function () {
    elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    url = jQuery(this).attr("alt");
    xava(url, elementID);
});
```

I am trying to animate an image off the screen and fade when a viewer clicks the image and then redirect to a page. All the parts of this code except the animate are working - any thoughts!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `animate callback` in jquery

```
function xava(target_url, elementID) {
    jQuery(elementID).animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
            left: "+=135"
        }, 1500, function() { 
              window.location.href = target_url;
     });
}

jQuery('[id^="nav-arrow"]').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    url = jQuery(this).attr("alt");
    xava(url, elementID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
function xava(target_url, elementID) {
    jQuery(elementID).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=135"
    }, 1500,function(){
        window.location.href = target_url;
    });
}
```